# How to Write a simple Assembly Program

Tags: assembly

I'm too amatuer. I want to compile program below in an assembly IDE, I mean I want to write a simple console application:

```
X DB 18
MOV AL,-18
ADD AL,X
```

I want to see AL's value as output on console screen, How can I run this simple code? which codes should I add to it?

Comment: Have you looked on Google, for example, into [this book](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) ?

Comment: Nobody at SO will do your work for you. What have you tried?

Comment: I have a book myself, but it won't explain how to write and compile codes in an IDE. For example it explain what is ADD and will show an exmaple just like in my question. I have searched google too, but its codes are not simple and I can not undrestand them. I want to know how to compile above code in IDE and I can not undestand why someones will vote my questions down :(

Comment: Please give us some more info. I'm sure whatever IDE you're using came with a "hello world" example. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Howdy, Stranger" as they say in the movies...

As you realize, you need more code. First thing to learn is to exit cleanly - the CPU doesn't know when you're done. Depends on what OS. "ExitProcess", probably - usually it's Windoze when they don't say. :)

"How do I display a number?" is probably the most frequently asked beginner question of all time. You could "just call printf", or (better?) convert the number to text (doesn't matter which OS) and print it (depends on OS). You've got a book? What does it say? (I'll second DCoder's recommendation of Dr. Carter's tute!)

Does the IDE you have in mind have a Friendly Manual? Read it. (an IDE isn't worth installing, IMHO, but some people like 'em)

You've got a problem in the code you show. The CPU will try to execute the number 18 as if it were an instruction. You want to separate "code" from "data". The exact syntax depends on which assembler you're using.

If you'll provide "which architecture" (looks like x86), "which OS", and "which assembler" you'll probably get better help.

Best,
Frank